# Yii, dual criteria in single relation

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, foreign-key-relationship

i have problem with second criteria on the same fields in relation

```
$criteria->with = array( 'Rel1',
                         'Rel1.Rel2' => ['alias'=>'attrType']);
$criteria->condition = 'Type=:type';
// first condition with Re1.value and Rel2.name - without second works fine
$criteria->addCondition("attrType.name='start' AND Rel1.value <= NOW()");

// second criteria with Re1.value and Rel2.name
$criteria->addCondition("attrType.name='end' AND Rel1.value > NOW()");

$criteria->order = 'Rel1.value DESC';

$criteria->params = [':type'=> 22];
$result = SomeModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

without second condition i have multiple records with start and end names. If i run with second condition i have 0 records found. pls help :/

Answer (score 0):

Your mixed condition will look like:

```
attrType.name='start' AND attrType.name='end' AND 
    Rel1.value <= NOW() AND Rel1.value > NOW()
```

And this part `Rel1.value <= NOW() AND Rel1.value > NOW()` is always false

Comment: Thanks for response Alexander. How to write these conditions to be independent. Its possible to use the same relation twice for different conditions ?